# SSL handshake problems with Qt 5.9 only when deployed in client

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ssl

I have a desktop application built in Qt 5.9 using MinGw in Windows, it pulls data from a database and displays it in the GUI in a organized manner.

Deploy of the project in release configuration **is working fine in 4 different computers that i tested** (windows 10 and windows 7)

But, in my client's computer, there are SSL handshake errors whenever a connection is tried.

Error that occurs is:

```
qml: Error during SSL handshake: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Current solutions that i found here and tried:

- Deploy openssl newest dlls in my release folder (alongside qt's dlls)
- Implement ignoreSslErros(), as in the code bellow:

  ```
  QObject::connect(_socket, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), _socket,SLOT(ignoreSslErrors()));
  ```

Where the signal and slot used are defined in QWebSocket's documentation.

SLOT: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#ignoreSslErrors

SIGNAL: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#sslErrors

This implementation didn't work.

I got to the point of remote accessing my client's computer and running Qt in debug configuration, and the only thing i got was these build warnings that dont occur when i build on my computer:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_alpn_protos
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_alpn_selected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the warnings I would suggest that the OpenSSL library at the clients computer does not support TLS 1.1+ but that the server requires it. And while you might have attempted to provide the new SSL libraries these messages show that your program does not use these new libraries.

Comment: This helped me get to the problem, i downgraded the server TLS requirement to 1.0. We use Caddy (https://caddyserver.com/) and i had to change the caddyfile. Thanks!